# Does the timeout parameter in Python's sqlite3 module affect the speed of normal transactions?

Tags: android, python, sqlite, sl4a

I am running a Python script on an Android phone using [SL4A](http://www.github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) (sadly now basically dead).  SL4A provides Python 2.6.

This script (along with some other processes) accesses an sqlite database using Python's built in [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module.  As it is running on an extremely low end phone, this is creating concurrency problems as database writes between processes are clashing, resulting in frequent `OperationalError: database is locked` exceptions.

To deal with this, I've increased the `timeout` parameter in the `sqlite3.connect` call (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection) for the documentation) to 20 seconds from the default 5 seconds.  According to the docs, this will increase the time that sqlite waits before throwing the `database is locked` exception.

**My question is: will this increase in the timeout also affect the performance of other transactions, i.e. those that are not blocked by another process?  Or is this only a timeout for this purpose alone?**

I'm concerned because there seems to be a drop in performance after I changed this parameter.  Given the very limited environment I'm working in, I haven't been able to figure out how to objectively test performance, so this perception might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) matters only if two transactions actually conflict.